# How to call a class using jToggleButton?

Tags: java, swing, class

I am developing a small screen capture application in java.i found a example to select rectangular area from here.[(this is that question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948122/drawing-a-bounding-rectangle-to-select-what-area-to-record).i used another jframe and add a toggle button to call the Rectangular selection class.i create  a object of Rectangular selection class when the toggle button is selected . Now i have to questions,

1. I used following code to create the selection class  object 
   But if the selection  object  is exists it create a new object. How to stop this ?

   ```
    if (sn == null) {   
       if (btn_selection.isSelected()) {
           sn = new SnipIt();
       } else {
           sn.frame.dispose();
       }
   }
   ```

2.to close the selection  class it use this code line,

```
    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(sl).dispose();
```

So i created a method  called closeSelection and insert above code line.but when i call this method returns a nullpointexception,

```
public void closeSelection() {
        SelectionPane sl=new SelectionPane();
        SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(sl).dispose();

    }
```

I know my code has many mistakes. So please show those and give me a solution.Highly appreciate your help  ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For example by adding a simple condition `if (sn == null) sn = new SnipIt();`. `null` is the value when an object "does not exist".
2. You have to use a reference to the actual `sn` Object from your first code snippet. Maybe store a reference to it in a field.
   Your attempt fails because:

   - it's an entirely different thing you try to get rid of (you make a `new` one just to dispose of it).
   - it's not attached to the actual view hierarchy so it doesn't have a window.

Comment: thanks.but i tried to dispose the jframe in that class.same exception?

Comment: @stackquestions Is `sn` added to the window somewhere? I.e. can you see the pane when you run the program? If not then it has no window either.

Comment: Now,but there is a jframe in the class?

Comment: @stackquestions swing does not care whether there are other things in the class. You'll have to add them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086936/java-adding-components-to-jframe to the frame

Comment: OK thanks a lot.i'll try that or i'll try to change the class file :-).